# CSS Performance: Zoomable background image with <img> vs ::before with background-image

Tags: html, css

I'm noticing some lag from some of my images, and I was curious on what the most efficient way of loading a zoomable background image would be: Img tag vs a pseudo element with a background image.

My goal is to not have lag on a high quality image.

Which of these would be best from a performance perspective for zoomable background image?

```css
* {
  padding: 0;
  margin: 0;
  box-sizing: border-box;
}

.card-list {
  display: flex;
  justify-content: center;
  gap: 20px;
  padding: 20px;
}

.card {
  height: 300px;
  width: 250px;
  position: relative;
  box-shadow: 0 0 5px grey;
  overflow: hidden;
  border-radius: 20px;
  background-color: #0004;
}

.card-text {
  display: flex;
  align-items: flex-end;
  color: white;
  font-size: 24px;
  font-family: Arial;
  padding: 20px;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
}

.background-image {
  position: absolute;
  object-fit: cover;
  object-position: center;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
  z-index: -1;
}

.card:hover .background-image,
.psuedo-bg-img:hover::before {
  transform: scale(1.1);
}

.psuedo-bg-img {
  position: relative;
}

.psuedo-bg-img::before {
  content: '';
  background-image: url('https://source.unsplash.com/random');
  background-position: center;
  background-size: cover;
  background-repeat: no-repeat;
  position: absolute;
  height: 100%;
  width: 100%;
  z-index: -1;
  transition: transform .4s ease;
}
```

```html
<div class="card-list">
  <div class="card">
    <img class="background-image" src="https://source.unsplash.com/random">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3>&lt;img&gt; as Background</h3>
    </div>
  </div>

  <div class="card psuedo-bg-img">
    <div class="card-text">
      <h3>Pseudo Elem w/ Background Image</h3>
    </div>
  </div>
</div>
```